# Using Pandas to parse a JSON column w/nested values in a huge CSV

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a huge CSV file (3.5GB and getting bigger everyday) which has normal values and one column called 'Metadata' with nested JSON values. My script is as below and the intention is simply to convert the JSON column into normal columns for each of its key-value pairs. I am using Python3 (Anaconda; Windows).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import datetime as dt

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

for df in pd.read_csv("source.csv", engine='c', 
    dayfirst=True, 
    encoding='utf-8', 
    header=0,
    nrows=10,
    chunksize=2,
    converters={'Metadata':json.loads}):

    ## parsing code comes here

    with open("output.csv", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as ofile:
        df.to_csv(ofile, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

And the column has JSON in the following format:

```
{  
   "content_id":"xxxx",
   "parental":"F",
   "my_custom_data":{  
      "GroupId":"NA",
      "group":null,
      "userGuid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "deviceGuid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "connType":"WIFI",
      "channelName":"VOD",
      "assetId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "GroupName":"NA",
      "playType":"VOD",
      "appVersion":"2.1.0",
      "userEnvironmentContext":"",
      "vodEncode":"H.264",
      "language":"English"
   }
}
```

The desired output is to have all the above key-value pairs as columns. The dataframe will have other non-JSON columns to which I need to add the columns parsed from the above JSON. I tried `json_normalize` but I am not sure how to apply `json_normalize` to a Series object and then convert it (or explode it) into multiple columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `json_normalize()` on the series directly, and then use [`pandas.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) to merge the new dataframe with the existing dataframe:

```
pd.concat([df, json_normalize(df['Metadata'])])
```

You can add a `.drop('Metadata', axis=1)` if you no longer need the old column with the JSON datastructure in it.

The columns produced for the `my_custom_data` nested dictionary will have `my_custom_data.` prefixed. If all the names *in* that nested dictionary are unique, you could drop that prefix with a [`DataFrame.rename()` operation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
json_normalize(df['Metadata']).rename(
    columns=lambda n: n[15:] if n.startswith('my_custom_data.') else n)
```

If you are using some other means to convert each dictionary value to a flattened structure (say, with [`flatten_json`](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten), then you want to use `Series.apply()` to process each value and  then return each resulting dictionary as a `pandas.Series()` object:

```
def some_conversion_function(dictionary):
    result = something_that_processes_dictionary_into_a_flat_dict(dictionary)
    return pd.Series(something_that_processes_dictionary_into_a_flat_dict)
```

You can then concatenate the result of the `Series.apply()` call (which will be a dataframe) back onto your original dataframe:

```
pd.concat([df, df['Metadata'].apply(some_conversion_function)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... the reason I'm looping over it is that read_csv returns an Iterator when you use chunksize=xxx.... Meanwhile, I am also getting a KeyError: 'group' from json_normalize.

Comment: @A.Ali: ah, my mistake, I missed the chunksize argument there.

Comment: Apparently, json_normalize doesn't deal well with my json. It gives me a KeyError: 'group'. I'm having better success using the flatten_json library. Now I have a python dict and need to create a dataframe using a dict and then append it to the existing dataframe.

Comment: @A.Ali: if you have a flat dictionary (all values are scalars), just create a `Series()` directly from that, using `df[columnname].apply(pd.Series)`; this returns a new dataframe, use `pd.concat()` just like with `json_normalize()`.

Comment: I went for this solution: def xflatten(js):
    d = flatten_json.flatten(js)
    for key, value in d.items():
        d[key] = [d[key]]
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='columns') .... AND ...         newdf = pd.concat([df.drop(['Metadata'], axis=1), df.Metadata.apply(xflatten)], axis=1) ... but it prints the column in a "pretty" format in my csv, lol

Comment: @A.Ali: why did you return a dataframe? Just return `pd.Series(d)`, without wrapping each value in a list.

Comment: `def xflatten(js): return pd.Series(flatten_json.flatten(js))`, then `pd.concat([df.drop(['Metadata'], axis=1), df.Metadata.apply(xflatten)])`

Comment: Got it! It works!! Please edit your answer so that I can mark it as the final one! Major thanks!