# Parse JSON column in Pandas or R Dataframe

Tags: r, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm dealing with a CSV with JSON data for the first time. I have uploaded the CSV file into Python (and I try also in R) as a dataframe. The CSV looks like this:

[image: Table Example]

This file is about sales. In every row I have the purchase details. One client can buy several products. I have lots of columns with details like delivery address, payment, etc.  The column **ITEMS** has JSON data inside (in Python is an Object type). What I want is to flatten that column into several columns and join them into the original dataframe.
The JSON looks like this (Notice that this client have bought two items, so I'll have to join the new columns and "repeat" the row with the client info):

```
[
   {
      "_id": {
         "$oid": "5fff7d777bdb300010b1f172"
      },
      "product": {
         "productCategories": [
            {
               "$oid": "2afe7b8b3a2c4e1b4a8b22f5"
            },
            {
               "$oid": "ca9bf1e1d9adf5b170b12fae"
            }
         ],
         "_id": {
            "$oid": "5ffc9c35fc8985001803d8b5"
         },
         "title": "Rice",
         "productType": {
            "$oid": "e1f2a11798b7f81ce44a5696"
         },
         "store": {
            "$oid": "5ffb729242ad2200107dcb42"
         },
         "price": 50,
         "stockMethod": {
            "_id": {
               "$oid": "5ffc9c49fc8985001803d8b7"
            },
            "value": "always"
         },
         "stock": null,
         "showInStore": true,
         "available": true,
         "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-11T18:43:01.103Z"
         },
         "modifiedAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-13T23:08:39.102Z"
         },
         "__v": 0
      },
      "quantity": 1
   },
   {
      "_id": {
         "$oid": "5fff7d777bdb300010b1f175"
      },
      "product": {
         "productCategories": [
            {
               "$oid": "d4abd6888580e00d9f746cac"
            },
            {
               "$oid": "a018049c6fc0253ee5aa6a8f"
            }
         ],
         "_id": {
            "$oid": "5ffcaa90fc8985001803d97c"
         },
         "title": "Beans",
         "productType": {
            "$oid": "e1f2a11798b7f81ce44a5696"
         },
         "store": {
            "$oid": "5ffb729242ad2200107dcb42"
         },
         "price": 130,
         "stockMethod": {
            "_id": {
               "$oid": "5ffcaa90fc8985001803d97d"
            },
            "value": "alwasy"
         },
         "stock": null,
         "showInStore": true,
         "available": true,
         "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-11T19:44:16.004Z"
         },
         "modifiedAt": {
            "$date": "2021-01-13T23:08:39.102Z"
         },
         "__v": 0
      },
      "quantity": 1
   }
]
```

I have tried different solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990123/using-pandas-to-parse-a-json-column-w-nested-values-in-a-huge-csv) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680272/parsing-a-json-string-which-was-loaded-from-a-csv-using-pandas) but I can't solve it.
For example, I've tried:

```
import json
from io import StringIO
stdf = orders['items'].apply(json.loads)
stlst = list(stdf)
stjson = json.dumps(stlst)
pd.read_json(StringIO(stjson))
```

And I get something like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a file called `data.json` you can do in R:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

read_json("data.json", simplifyVector = TRUE) %>%
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   `_id`$`$oid`  product$productC… $`_id`$`$oid` $title $productType$`$… quantity
#>   <chr>         <list>            <chr>         <chr>  <chr>               <int>
#> 1 5fff7d777bdb… <df [2 × 1]>      5ffc9c35fc89… Rice   e1f2a11798b7f81…        1
#> 2 5fff7d777bdb… <df [2 × 1]>      5ffcaa90fc89… Beans  e1f2a11798b7f81…        1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And for json data inside a csv file:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'jsonlite'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     flatten

data <- tibble(
  id = c(1,2),
  data = c("{\"foo\":1, \"bar\":2}", "{\"foo\":10, \"bar\":20}")
)
data
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id data                      
#>   <dbl> <chr>                     
#> 1     1 "{\"foo\":1, \"bar\":2}"  
#> 2     2 "{\"foo\":10, \"bar\":20}"

data %>%
  mutate(
    data = data %>% map(~ parse_json(.x, simplifyVector = TRUE))
  ) %>%
  unnest_wider(data)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>      id   foo   bar
#>   <dbl> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     2
#> 2     2    10    20
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I don't have a JSON file, I have a CSV file with one column with JSON format. The rest of the columns are integers, strings, etc.

Comment: @Pablo I added a new example

Comment: that works. I'm trying to figure out how to do it in Python, but for now I can use R first and then export the file to Python